# How gdal_rasterize works - how it interpolates / resample values?

Tags: rasterization, resampling, gdal-rasterize

I have huge number of points saved as shapefile.

I created an empty raster file with low spatial resolution. Next, I applied *gdal_rasterize* on mentioned .shp and used low resolution raster as destination.

It works, but since I didn't provided an resampling method, I wonder which algorithm has been applied to prepare raster for me.
Unfortunately, I can't find this information within the GDAL documentation: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`gdal_rasterize`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) doesn't perform any interpolation or resampling.

By default it updates pixels under a point, on the line render path, or whose center point is within the polygon. But you can choose to update all pixels touched by lines or polygons with the `-at` flag.

> **-at:**
>
> Enables the ALL_TOUCHED rasterization option so that all pixels
>   touched by lines or polygons will be updated, not just those on the
>   line render path, or whose center point is within the polygon.
>   Defaults to disabled for normal rendering rules.

If you want to interpolate between your points, you can use [`gdal_grid`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html).